# How get the value of a form::select in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Im new with Laravel framework and need to get the form::select value. In this moment the controller get the index of the select. I was searching and get no answer. There's my code

ProductosController.php

```
public function crearProducto()
    {

        $nombre = Input::get('nombre');
        $precio = Input::get('precio');
        $descripcion = Input::get('descripcion');
        $sub = Input::get('subcategorias');
        $imagen = Input::get('imagen');
        $opcionTela = Input::get('opcionTela');
        $insertArray = array('NOMBRE_PRODUCTO' =>  $nombre, 'DESCRIPCION' => $descripcion, 'PRECIO_PRODUCTO' => $precio, 'RUTAIMAGEN_PRODUCTO' => $imagen, 'TIENETELA' => $opcionTela, 'NOMBRE_SUBCATEGORIA' => $sub);
        $resultado = Producto::create($insertArray);

    }
```

In the view the select is like that. That select is populate by the database.

```
{{ Form::select('subcategorias', $subcategorias, Input::old('subcategorias'), array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'categoriaProducto'))}}
```

When I insert the product in database the value of subcategoria is 0 or 1. Note that I have only 2 options in the select.

Comment: can you `print_r(Input::all());` above your `$nombre`?

Comment: how are you getting the data for `$subcategorias`, sounds like your values are the default array keys

Comment: This is how i get the array
$subcategorias = DB::table('subcategoria')->lists('NOMBRE_SUBCATEGORIA');
  return View::make('Productos.create', array('subcategorias' => $subcategorias));

Comment: The result of the print_r(Input::al()); is 


Array ( [_token] => KYz98HNkXvBttGUx93ucunvUFWzjZDK2t9FjFhIj [nombre] => ssa [precio] => 1231 [descripcion] => asadsas [subcategorias] => 1 [imagen] => guia de Laravel.txt [opcionTela] => 0 )

Comment: I need the subcatgorias[1] value and dont know how i guess he is taking the index and not the value any idea?

Comment: Please, post print_r of array $subcategories after it been initialized from database.

Comment: Array ( [0] => Sillas de Cocina [1] => Sillas de Sala ) there's the print_r and get 0 or 1 I need to get the value of that